# How can I fix my issue with my jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

So I am currently building my own personal website and have run into an issue with my jQuery. I am trying to make a responsive navigation bar that will disappear on mobile and then reappear when you click a button. I have the mobile side working fine but I want to make it so you can switch between mobile and desktop view and the navigation just switch over to fit the platform. it works fine if you dont close the navigation bar on the mobile and then slide the window to desktop but if you close the navigation bar on mobile it now has no class and will at display: none;. It needs to have the class of showing to show but for some reason when i put a reset button to fix the issue when you click the reset button it does nothing even though the jQuery is setup for it to add the class of showing to my navigation bar her is the html file i have setup.

```
<header>
    <a href="#menu" id="reset">Reset</a>
    <center>
        <h1 class="title">Theme</h1>
        <p class="kicker">Kicker</p>
        <a class="btn-a" href="#home">
            <span class="btn-1">Get Started Now</span>
        </a>
    </center>
</header>
<nav class="nav-bar" id="home">
    <div class="handle" id="click">
        <div id="hamburger" class="hamburglar is-closed">
            <div class="burger-icon">
                <div class="burger-container">
                    <span class="burger-bun-top"></span>
                    <span class="burger-filling"></span>
                    <span class="burger-bun-bot"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- svg ring containter -->
            <div class="burger-ring">
                <svg class="svg-ring">
                    <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4" d="M 34 2 C 16.3 2 2 16.3 2 34 s 14.3 32 32 32 s 32 -14.3 32 -32 S 51.7 2 34 2" />
                </svg>
            </div>
            <!-- the masked path that animates the fill to the ring -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <a class="link" href="#contact">
            <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
        <a class="link" href="#services">
            <li>Services</li>
        </a>
        <a class="link" href="#home">
            <li>Home</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

the reset button has an id of reset. and here is my jQuery for the menu

```
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js\jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <!-- My JavaScript and jQuery scripts -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#click').on('click', function(){
        $('#menu').slideToggle(500).toggleClass('showing');
      });
    });
    </script> <!--End Script 1 -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#reset').on('click', function(){
        $('#menu').addClass('showing');
      });
    });
    </script> <!--End Script 2 -->
```

Can someone please help me solve this I am not sure whats going on.

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle for this

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this situation by CSS media query.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #menu { display:block !important;}
}
```

You can set min-width value as your expected screen from where you want to show your menu.